# Docker Minimal Image PyInstaller Binary File?

Tags: python, docker, pyinstaller

So I have a Docker image that basically consists of compiling python source code to standalone executable with `RUN pyinstaller --onefile app.py` in the build stage (after all deps for pyinstaller and python installed). It then copies the standalone executable to a scratch image using `COPY --from=builder /dist/app /app`. It executes the binary on entrypoint. However in the scratch image, I am getting `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"` error when the binary is executed. It is statically linked.

**My Searches**

I fouund many posts talking about dos vs unix newlines, and I used `dos2unix`, but since it is a binary file, as I found, `dos2unix` didn't work. I also tried copying in the .spec file, to no avail. A solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you solve it? I get the same trouble.Don't know how to continue.

Comment: the problem was that it still has a dependency on standard dynamic libraries, BUT the pyinstaller FAQ outlines some tools for making the executable static https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ#gnulinux