# Does pyinstaller have any parameters like gcc -static?

Tags: python, docker, pyinstaller

I have a similar question to this : [Is there a way to compile a Python program to binary and use it with a Scratch Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62581924/is-there-a-way-to-compile-a-python-program-to-binary-and-use-it-with-a-scratch-d)?

In this [page](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch/?tab=reviews), I saw that someone said that a C application runs well when compiled with `-static`.

So I have a new question: does `pyinstaller` have any parameters like `gcc -static` to  make a python application run well in a Scratch Docker image?

Comment: This seems like the same question as the one you linked to?  In particular note the first comment on that question that `pyinstaller` doesn't actually produce a binary.

Comment: @DavidMaze That's not true, pyinstaller does indeed create a binary with the "-F" and "--onefile" parameters.. See: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What command are you running? Take a look at the docs.

Comment: @Carley I want  run python applications in scratch image,like go application run in scratch after build.Any ideas?

Comment: @David Maze pyinstall could build to a binary?

Comment: Duplicate question

Comment: I think this question is heaviliy misworded. It comes down to asking the same question I did (the one linked) that is asking is there a way to use a python file with the Docker from scratch image to keep it small. I ended up using Google's distroless image which results in a very similar answer. This question ends up compiling python to a static file (one that commenters had said was impossible on my question). So this question should be: 'Can pyinstaller be used to create a static file for Docker to use with scratch images (for a small image size)' The answer: yes, with the `-F` tag.

Comment: I will also add that OP's chief complaint with my answer was the image's size. The google distroless image does include the python llibrary (which is pretty big.) However, in this answer he / she appears to use a one line python file to test it out (print a message), which may not hold up for a large project. Testing this with a flask web server (one of my projects) shows they are very similar in size (MB range), and  I suspect that adding more packages in requirements.txt makes super close in size. Hence, my downvote

Comment: @DavidFrick First, I sayed,it was similar question to yours,not the same.You asked how it could run in a scratch image,but I care about how it could be complied to  a fully-static  binary.Running  in scratch image just a way to check, wheather it had been complied rightly to  a fully-static binnray.Second,you compromised with the answer which not show you ,how to run in a scratch image(Your question is it ,right?) , maybe you did not try to solve the issue by yourself.

Comment: @DavidFrick  Third, about the imag's size.I care about how could it by complied to a fully-static  binary,docker to a image just a way to check it. What;s more,give it in your question,We both want to find a way to run a python application in scratch image,just  a possible of run in scratch,Never say it is the best ,or , a better way to docker a python application image.Fourth,it is sure that,someone else may had a python project,the answer clould  be useful for them.

Comment: @DavidFrick fifth, the `-F` means to complie to a single file,not mean to complie to a full-static binary,you can get more  difference in [links](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ#gnulinux).

Comment: I think the question is 'is there a way to generate an executable such that running `ldd` against the executable shows no dependencies? At least that is my questiton :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the question [Docker Minimal Image PyInstaller Binary File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61262156/docker-minimal-image-pyinstaller-binary-file?noredirect=1#comment111416388_61262156)'s  commands,I get the [links](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ#gnulinux) about how to make python binary to static,which like the go application demo,say hello world in scratch.

And I do a single ,easy demo,app.py:

```
print("test")
```

Then,do docker build with the Dockerfile:

```
FROM bigpangl/python:3.6-slim AS complier
WORKDIR /app
COPY app.py ./app.py

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential patchelf \
    && pip install staticx pyinstaller \ 
    && pyinstaller -F app.py \
    && staticx /app/dist/app  /tu2k1ed

FROM scratch
WORKDIR /
COPY --from=complier /tu2k1ed /
COPY --from=complier /tmp /tmp
CMD ["/tu2k1ed"]
```

Get the image below, just 7.22M(I am not sure if could see the pic):

[image]

Try to run by code `docker run test`,successfully:

[image]

PS:

With my tests

- the `CMD` must write by ['xxx'] not xxx direct.
- `/tmp` directory is required in the demo.
- other python application not test ,jsut the demo codes about print

Answer (score 2):

The `-F` and `--onefile` parameters should do what you are looking to do. You'll likely want to take a look at your `specs` file and tweak accordingly.

Using `--onefile` will compile it into (you guessed it) one file. And you can include binaries with `--add-binary` parameter.

These pages in the docs may have some useful details on all of the parameters: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-binary-files
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

Comment: I know **-F** can build to onefile ,or no *-F* ,many files is also I can accpet.But this way,after build by pyinstaller,could not run well in scratch(could run on linux system level,but not scratch).Could any ideas?

Comment: Ah, I think I see. Could it be an issue with CR/LFs linux vs. windows? This similar question (about docker not scratch, sorry) mentions newlines potentially being an issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61262156/docker-minimal-image-pyinstaller-binary-file. Sorry, that's all I have for now but will try to revisit this later.

Comment: Many similar question had been asked in stackoverflow.com.But no right solution got.I tried to code on linux and build image,not run go .So it may not a question about CR/LFs linux vs windows.What's more,the error comes from a binary,not source code.So ,hard to me .

Comment: Even with -F or --onefile, running `ldd` against the executable clearly shows it is not statically linked, I see a dependency on `libc.so.6` among others